# SugarCRM or SuiteCRM Quote Line are not displayed when created with SOAP API

Tags: c#, soap, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm integrating an backend web application with SuiteCRM and I'm using the SOAP API extensivly.

From the backend application I'm creating an Quote (AOS_Quotes) and I'm adding some line items (aos_products_quotes) to the quote. Once the objects are created with the api I'm setting an relationship between them. The relationship is successfully created, however when I navigate to the SuiteCRM web interface and open the quote the line items are not displayed. From the API I can confirm that the relationship by retrieving the line items for that quote.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on the SuiteCRM forum and I got the answer https://suitecrm.com/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/2865-suitecrm-quote-line-are-not-displayed-when-created-with-soap-api

Basically you need to provide the parent_type="AOS_Quotes" and then all will work.